# Python MySQL Parameter Query Programming Error: 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, limit, offset

I want to query MySQL tables using python program but I got this error:

> ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10' OFFSET '0'' at line 1

The confusing thing is that when I don't use variables, the query runs perfectly as it is shown below:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM DB.Table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0"

cur.execute(query)

records = cur.fetchall()

for record in records:
    print(record)
```

But I need to select data batch by batch and I have to do the above command in a for loop. And I need to define variables. But I got error 1064. Here is the code with error:

```
i = 0
p = str(i)
j = 10
q = str(j)

cur = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM DB.Table LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"

cur.execute(query,(q,p,))

records = cur.fetchall()

for record in records:
    print(record)
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, do not convert parameterized values to string as error shows single quotes:

```
i = 0
j = 10

cur = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM DB.Table LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"

cur.execute(query, (j, i))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But when I use it with a left join `query = "SELECT * FROM DB.Table1 LIMIT %s OFFSET %s LEFT JOIN DB.Table2 ON Table1.id =Table2.id"` and `cur.execute(query, (j, i)) ` I faced with the same error.

Comment: `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` can only run at the very end of a query to limit the entire joined resultset. Consider using a subquery or CTE then join in outer level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cur.execute(query % (q,p))` or

```
query = "SELECT * FROM DB.Table LIMIT {} OFFSET {}"
cur.execute(query.format(q, p))
```

Comment: Note: This answer change OP's use of SQL parameterization for the ill-advised string SQL concatenation.